# How do I serialize from request's Response with JSON into a typed struct?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I don't understand how I can convert a `requests::Response` to a serde JSON object. I tried this:

```
extern crate requests;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

fn get_json() -> requests::Response {
    let response = requests::get("Fancy URL").unwrap();

    return response;
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    iso: String,
    number: String,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data = get_json();
    let res = serde_json::from_reader(data);

    if res.is_ok() {
        let p: MyStruct = res.unwrap();
        println!("The name is {}", p.name);
    } else {
        println!("Could not parse JSON!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The crate `requests` has not been updated in 3 years. Consider using [`reqwest`](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) instead, then following its documentation to retrieve the full response body.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (**and their versions**) are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can find [an example](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/#parsing-json-as-strongly-typed-data-structures). Something like this may work:

```
let p: MyStruct = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
```

Comment: *Something like this should work* — it's far more useful to provide a tested example that you are **sure** works.